# PHP to SMS with character Limits

Tags: php, smtp, sms

I'm having a bit of trouble getting text messages to send, specifically to T-Mobile.  I happen to know that TMobile has a strict character limit of 160 characters.  If it's above 160 characters, it's supposed to switch to an image message (I believe it's called MMS).

Now, when I send a very simple text to my ATT phone, it reads:

```
FRM:My Name
MSG:
Message
```

And the PHP code for that, sent through my Fedora terminal:

```
mail("1238675309@txt.att.net", "", "Message");
```

Now, when we have a very short message sent through PHP to a TMobile number, it goes off without a hitch, because even with the FRM and MSG lines, it's less than 160 characters.

Naturally, this leads me to hypothesize that it's the additional lines that are causing a long text message to be bumped over 160 characters, and Tmobile doesn't know how to handle it.  My preliminary tests with a friend's TMobile phone seems to confirm this suspicion.

So, my question is, is there a way to send the message and only the message to a phone?  Or will it always have these additional "meta" info?

The constraints I have:

- No external APIs.
- Using PHP5.1  If it's absolutely necessary, I may be able to use java, a python script, or Bash. I'm not familiar enough with other languages.
- Server is CentOS.

I don't have enough time/permission to totally retool the system that's already existing from a previous developer.

I'm willing to keep an open mind on this.  If you guys know of some other reason why this is not working, I'd be happy to hear your comments.

Comment: You can *probably* use a conditional statement with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: Yes, but you have the meta data being added on Tmobile's side, right?  So up until the moment where I use mail(), it would be less than 160 characters.  And after mail() is called, then I have no control over what is received.  Or am I greatly mistaken?

Comment: I know you said no APIs but TWILIO is super easy and it's dirt cheap, like a half cent per text.

Comment: I don't know that API and T-Mobile, so I couldn't tell you more on that subject. The logic with using `strlen` as my suggestion would be to restrict the user right away with that, and inform them that the length has exceeded the allowed number of characters. You can achieve that with pure PHP or a mix of JS/PHP (even Ajax). On success, execute `mail()`

Comment: `mail()` doesn't really sends SMS. So you are emailing a Gateway that translates your mail to a SMS, that's carrier dependant (ATT, TMobile, etc.) some carriers don't do that (or require a client to subscribe to a service to do that), so that may be why it is not working.

Also, looks like T-Mobile specifically has issues with that: http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/56327.